# Why table size doesn't change after vacuum full?

Tags: postgresql

Here is then code. Lets create table with 10000 rows of data.

DB version is PostgreSQL 9.5.3 on x86_64-suse-linux-gnu

```
drop table if exists test;

create table test as 
select gs as id, md5(gs::text) as value from generate_series(1,10000) gs;

create unique index test_id_pkey on test using btree(id);
alter table test add primary key using index test_id_pkey;
analyze test;

select pg, pg_size_pretty(pg) pz from pg_relation_size('test') pg;

Results of last query: 672kb
Now

delete from test where id > 1000;
```

size of table was reduced like 10 times. Now lets vacuum it. According documentation vacuum full make of copy of table on disk and write into it only alive rows, those are only 10% of original.

```
vacuum full test;
select pg, pg_size_pretty(pg) pz from pg_relation_size('test') pg;

Still size of table is 672kb
```

Let's try trick with **alter table** statement which will do the same. Create a new copy of table on disk and write into it only alive rows

```
alter table jenkins.test alter column id type int;
select pg, pg_size_pretty(pg) pz from pg_relation_size('test') pg;

Still size of table is 672kb;
```

Now let's create a new table copy of current table sized 672kb

```
drop table if exists test1;
create table test1 as 
select * from test;

create unique index test1_id_pkey on test1 using btree(id);
alter table test1 add primary key using index test1_id_pkey;
analyze test1;
select pg, pg_size_pretty(pg) pz from pg_relation_size('test1') pg
```

Surprisingly size of this table is just 72kb. Vacuuming throw warning messages

```
INFO:  "test": found 0 removable, 10000 nonremovable row versions in 84 pages
DETAIL:  9000 dead row versions cannot be removed yet.
```

It is just an example. I tried to add more row up to 1_000_000 still the same.
When table row become removable?
How to deal with such situations or to be ready to?

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is this message from `VACUUM (VERBOSE)`:

```
INFO:  "test": found 0 removable, 10000 nonremovable row versions in 84 pages
DETAIL:  9000 dead row versions cannot be removed yet.
```

That probably means that there ia a long running concurrent transaction that *might* still need the old row versions from before you issued the `DELETE`.

Terminate all log running transactions and it will work fine.

Comment: I thought about it. Those tables newly create, means there are no long transactions. I try to close connection and session and rerun vacuum. That didn't help. My current thought, there is some time gap between made some changes  and those changes flushed to wal log and pages released eventually.

Comment: Anyway now i checked again and found out that size is reduced. Which most probably means vacuum full just schedule procedure, not execute immediately.

Comment: No, it does execute immediately. There was a concurrent transaction that prevented `VACUUM` from removing the dead rows (this is the main reason why it is a bad idea to have long-running transaction). What removed the rows in your case was [autovacuum](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/routine-vacuuming.html#AUTOVACUUM). It just so happened that you deleted the data at the end of the table, and that is the only case where a regular `VACUUM` can shrink the table.

Comment: That's correct. It happen in Navicat, looks like it doesn't have autocommit enabled. In PgAdmin works as expected.